# Is .( ever legal in C# or VB.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, syntax

Can the sequence `.(` ever appear in C# or VB.Net code?
(Not in a string, comment, or XML literal, **EDIT**: or preprocessor directive)

I'm reasonably certain that the answer is no, but I'd like to make sure.

Comment: Note that while it may not be legal now, it could be in a future version of C# or VB.NET.  Microsoft adds features to its languages pretty frequently.

Comment: Just curious, but why do you ask?

Comment: @Ani: I'm trying to figure out what needs to be escaped in Razor code nuggets.  For example, `.[` is valid in VB.Net, but Razor ignores that.

Comment: this question makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Javed: If you're trying to parse a C# expression embedded in other text, and you see `.(`, can you always stop?   (without writing a complete C# parser)

Comment: I'm trying to understand how anyone can possibly answer this question by saying no unless they are extremely knowledgable about compiling C#.  How can you prove there are no purple unicorns?

Comment: yes! in a comment it could be a one-eyed smiley face... lol

Comment: @Ani SLaks' most recent comment provides a bit more clarity about the reason for this question.

Comment: @tster: I'm hooping for an answer from Eric Lippert.

Comment: @tster excellent point, deleting my answer.

Comment: +1 for stealing a few minutes of my time, making me think.

Comment: @Tony one-eyed unhappy face ;)

Comment: @tster: By reading the production rules in the grammar.

Comment: @Jason, the grammer doesn't mention the fact that it could occur in a string, but it still can occur there.

Comment: 1. The question explicitly stated "not in a string." 2. The grammar for `string-literal` is in section B.1.8 of the specification. There it effectively states that a string literal is composed of a sequence of Unicode characters, of which `.(` is a valid subsequence.

Comment: The part of me that shoulda been a lawyer loves this question ;)

Comment: This is really interesting!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only places that `.` appears in the grammar are:

```
real-literal:
    decimal-digits   .   decimal-digits ...
    .   decimal-digits ...

namespace-or-type-name:
    namespace-or-type-name   .   identifier ...


member-access:
    primary-expression   .   identifier ...
    predefined-type   .   identifier ...

qualified-alias-member   .   identifier ...

base-access:
    base   .   identifier

unbound-type-name:
    unbound-type-name   .   identifier

qualified-identifier: 
    qualified-identifier   .   identifier

member-name:
    interface-type   .   identifier

indexer-declarator:
    type   interface-type   .   this
```

(The ... means I have elided the remainder of the production rule.) In none of these cases is a `.(` valid as `.` is either followed by digits, a valid identifier, or the keyword `this`.

Comment: That's conclusive enough.  However, it doesn't cover VB.Net.

Comment: @SLaks: C# Language Specification 4.0.

Answer (score 20):

In C#, a `#region` segment allows any characters to follow it:

```
#region foo.(
// this is perfectly legal C#
#endregion
```

Note that in VB.Net this is not a concern because the region label has to be a valid string literal, so it has quotes:

```
#Region "foo.("
' quotes required
#End Region
```

It's also legal after `#error` and `#warn` which have no VB equivalent.

The biggest concern, though, is that you can have any arbitrary code inside of an `#if` block. In C#:

```
#if false
    foo.( perfectly legal
#endif
```

In VB.Net:

```
#If False Then
    foo.( perfectly legal
#End If
```

It's actually worse than that, because the VB version allows arbitrary expressions so you can't know if some code is actually VB unless you evaluate the expressions. In other words, parsing alone is not sufficient -- you have to evaluate too.

That said, analyzing the grammar in the C# Language Specification Version 4.0, Appendix B, the `.` character appears in the following lines:

```
real-literal:
    decimal-digits   .   decimal-digits   exponent-partopt   real-type-suffixopt
    .   decimal-digits   exponent-partopt   real-type-suffixopt

operator-or-punctuator:  one of
    {     }     [     ]     (     )     .     ,     :     ;

namespace-or-type-name:
    namespace-or-type-name   .   identifier   type-argument-listopt

member-access:
    primary-expression   .   identifier  type-argument-listopt
    predefined-type   .   identifier  type-argument-listopt
    qualified-alias-member   .   identifier

base-access:
    base   .   identifier

unbound-type-name:
    unbound-type-name   .   identifier   generic-dimension-specifieropt

qualified-identifier:
    qualified-identifier   .   identifier

member-name:
    interface-type   .   identifier

indexer-declarator:
    type   interface-type   .   this   [   formal-parameter-list   ]
```

Since a `.` is always followed by a decimal digit, an identifier, or a `this` token, the only way to have a `.(` sequence is to allow multiple `operator-or-punctuator` symbols next to each other. Looking up `operator-or-punctuator`, we see:

```
token:
    operator-or-punctuator
```

Since `token` is only used in lexical analysis, there's nothing to suggest that a `.` is legal followed by a `(` in regular code.

Of course that still leaves comments, literals, etc. which I leave out because you already know about those.

Comment: +1, but that's not really what I'm looking for; it's essentially a comment.  I'm going to edit the question to exclude this, but it's still a good answer.

Answer (score 10):

No reference to the grammar and completely unscientific, but here's my *guess*:

`.(` is not legal in C# (can't speak for VB.NET).

Outside of comments and string literals, I *think* `.` can only appear as:

1. The member access operator, which [must be followed by an identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691353%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Since identifiers may not begin with `(`, this is a no go.
2. As a decimal point in real literals, which [must be followed by a digit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691085%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). `(` is not a digit.

Finally, the `.` operator [is not overloadable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so `foo.(bar)` won't work either.

Comment: Minor point, but `5.` is a valid literal, not requiring a digit after the `.` Still can't figure out how to put a `(` right after it.

Comment: @Joel: `5.` not a valid literal as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Joel: Ani is correct.  Had it been a valid literal, you might be able to do _evil_ things by writing an `mscorlib` in which `System.Double` was a delegate.

Comment: @JoelRondeau, in JavaScript that is valid; in C# it isn't   EDIT: didn't see your last comment. nevermind

Answer (score 6):

Having perused the VB reference, I’m now confident that **the answer for VB is no**.

VB uses the character `.` for only three things: inside floating point number literals and for member access and nested name access.

Leaving aside XML literals, the only thing that may every appear behind a member access is an `IdentifierOrKeyword` (§1.105.6). Identifiers are very well-defined and they may only start with letters, underscores or, in the case of an escaped identifier, the character `[`.

The same goes for nested name access (and, for completeness’ sake, also in `With` blocks and field initialisers).

As for floating point literals, the point there **must** be followed by at least one more digit (§1.6.3).

Comment: Should mention LINQ to XML? Which [allows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384974.aspx) .@ and ... although not .( as far as I know

Comment: @MarkJ It *is* mentioned: XML literals were explicitly excluded from the question. I’m assuming that SLaks included Linq to XML in that.

Answer (score 5):

On this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2010/04/19/grammar.aspx I put a copy of the complete grammar for C#4 and VB10 in machine-readable format (EBNF & ANTLR) and human-readable (HTML). The HTML version includes the computed "may-follows" set for each token.

According to this, the "may-follows" set of PERIOD does not include LPAREN in either C#4 or VB10.

Unfortunately the grammars aren't quite complete. Nevertheless, within the VB/C# teams, these grammars are what we start with for a lot of our analysis. For instance...

- VB10 introduced "single-line statement lambdas" of the form "Sub() STMT". A lambda itself is an expression, and may appear in a list e.g. "Dim array = {Sub() STMT1, Sub() STMT2}". We had to be aware of ambiguities about what came after an expression and what came after a statement. For instance, "Dim x = Sub() Dim y = 5, z = 3" is ambiguous because the "z=3" might be part of the first OR the second Dim.
- VB10 introduced "implicit line continuation" feature, which is more or less analogous to allowing C# to include SEMICOLON anywhere in the source code. We had to figure out whether this would introduce any ambiguities. That's equivalent to asking whether a prefix of any sentence in the language is also itself a valid sentence. That's equivalent to figuring out whether the intersection of two context-free languages is empty. It's an undecidable problem in general, but not in the case of the VB grammar, which we were able to decide with additional "human insight" into the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they'll add anything like this to C#, would just look plain wrong.

I am not at all sure about VB.Net, though. just by looking at how they did generics, it seems that the VB.Net team doesn't have this "not looking weird" attitude.

So, if you build any kind of tool that should work with future versions of those languages, better watch out for VB.Net...

Comment: A very subjective “answer”. The “weird” look is entirely down to habit and I think that VB for the most part looks substantially less weird than languages which inherit the C syntax.

Comment: Yep, of course that has to be subjective. I don't think the VB.net team would deliberately create something weird-looking. Yet, their "kinda passes as not being too ugly" corresponds to my "o_O". And from all I've seen so far, the C# team has a similar "weirdness threshold" than me. Completely subjective, yes. But reproducible as well, which is pretty much my point why he can't be sure about VB.Net on this one.

Comment: Such as `.[` or `.<`, which are valid in VB.Net?

Comment: @slaks, I thought about the infamous with statement. It lets you call stuff of your "with instance" just by adding a "." in front of it. Could very well end up that they allow their indexers to be called this way in VB.Net 13.  x = new List(Of String)  with x  .(0).ToString() end with