# Create Error with custom text that prevents compiling in VB.NET (#error in C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, error-handling, user-defined

You can add a preprocessor directive to cause an error at compile time in C# like this:

```
#error This will cause a divide by zero
```

How can I do the same as [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5hedts0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in vb.net?

or

Is there another way to create an error that provides custom helpful information in the Errorlist.

**TLDR:** ***I want to do something like THIS in VB.NET:***

[image: photo taken from C# project]

Comment: Rather than just downvotes. Comments of what I need to clarify would be nice...

Comment: Not seeing any directive that does this. Here's the MSDN page for vb.net directives: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582331/is-ever-legal-in-c-sharp-or-vb-net#5582704) seems pretty sure there isn't any equivalent.

Comment: Not sure why there's downvotes and a close vote for being "unclear". This is actually a good, clear, concise question... try googling it, I haven't found anything.

Comment: To follow @LynnCrumbling idea, comparing [VB directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ah135z7.aspx) and [C# directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) leaves no real doubt about the answer...

Comment: @tnw Agreed -- I can't find anywhere that someone came up with a workable solution for this. There simply is no directive. The best you're going to be able to do, is just type text that doesn't compile... maybe something like:  `#if DEBUG (newline)  DON'T EVER COMPILE DEBUG BUILDS! (newline)
#end if`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way that you can achieve what you want. It is not perfect. But it does meet your criteria of:

- Prevents compiling
- Puts Custom text in the Error List Window

You first need to declare a variable with the custom text you want displayed with underscores in between each word. (Yes the underscores are annoying but they are necessary)

> Dim This_is_as_useful_a_description_as_your_gonna_get as String

This creates an unused variable. which in conjunction with the IDE's ability to treat warnings as errors will give you something close to what you are looking for:

[image]

You can turn on treat warnings as errors by going to your project properties and the compile tab. like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent to

```
#error
```

in VB.Net

I have found no way to add a meaningful error to prevent compiling.

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare a var with sure compiler error such as:

`Dim error As String = "This is as useful a description as your gonna get"`

thus avoiding all the underscores.
That will result automatically in a compiling error ("Keyword is not valid as an identifier"), not a warning.

Example:

```
#if _A_DEPRECATED_DEFINE_
DIM error As String = "remove the define: is deprecated!"
#end if
```

Comment: This does cause a compiler error, but the OP wanted the error text to appear in the Error List window in Visual Studio (not to simply produce a compiler error, which could be done in a number of ways).